# How to get video rotation angle when metadata rotation is not right?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, vlc, android-mediacodec

I have a video file, I get its resolution(3840x2160) and rotation(0) from the below codes:

```
        MediaMetadataRetriever retr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retr.setDataSource(mVideoFile);
        String height = retr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        String width = retr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
        String rotation = retr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
```

But actullay, the video rotation angle in degrees is not right, it should be 90, 2160x3840 resolution, so my video always failed to display correctly in my android application.

Interestingly, some 3rd-party video players (such as VLC) can detect the actual rotation for this video file, and its display is ok either, how did they do that?

Comment: no, finnaly I ignored this case.

Answer (score 4):

It's too late but probably it will help future visitors.

Following line will return rotation of video. Four possible value will be 0,90,180,270.

```
rotation = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION));
```

If the rotation is 90 or 270 the width and height will be transposed.

> [Android MediaMetadataRetriever wrong video height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879813/android-mediametadataretriever-wrong-video-height-and-width)

So swipe the width and height, if rotation is 90 or 270.

```
if(rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
{ 
 int swipe = width; 
 width = height; 
 height = swipe; 
}
```

Following is the complete code. I compare the result with MXPlayer result is same.

```
public static String getVideoResolution(File file)
{
    try
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(file.getPath());
        int width = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
        int height = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
        int rotation = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            rotation = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION));
        }
        retriever.release();

        if(rotation != 0)
        {
            if(rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
            {
                int swipe = width;
                width = height;
                height = swipe;
            }
        }

        return width + " x " + height;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Information not found.";
    }
}
```

Following is the code for setting screen orientation.

```
int width;
int height;
int rotation = 0;
try {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
    width = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
    height = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        rotation = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION));
    }
    retriever.release();

    if(rotation != 0)
    {
        if(rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
        {
            int swipe = width;
            width = height;
            height = swipe;
        }
    }
    this.setRequestedOrientation(width < height ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What about devices that run on Version below Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1?

Ans: I didn't know. But above code will work on most of devices.

**Following is the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56337044/8199772**

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer. This is not a very reliable way. You will most certainly get cases where the video does not have that metadata available. The most reliable way is to get a `Bitmap` from the video and getting the dimensions of that `Bitmap` as shown in my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56337044/8199772

Comment: Also, Samsung devices set their orientation differently. So if you use this you will end up having to handle rotation for different mobile providers.

Comment: I mention your answer link.