# Detecting if video was taken in portrait/landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I would like to confirm that what I am doing is indeed the correct way as some elements behave unexpected.

First, I have a landscape and portrait layout, as I understand, doing this will automatically detect if the phone is in portrait/landscape mode:

```
- layout
   - activity_video_player.xml
 - layout-land
   - activity_video_player.xml
```

Then when the user selects a video from the gallery, I check if the video was taking in landscape or portrait, by doing this (inside `OnCreate`):

```
int w;
int h;

MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(this, videoURI);
String height = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
String width = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
w = Integer.parseInt(width);
h = Integer.parseInt(height);

if (w > h) {  
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

I have tested this and it works fine, but I noticed some of my xml elements (play button) is placed incorrectly.

So my app flow is:

```
MainActivity --> SelectvidButton --> Gallery Intent --> VideoPlayActivity
```

---

**My Question**

Is this the correct way of doing this and if it is, is there any reason why some of the xml elements get placed incorrectly?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I noticed that this only happens when the activity is launched for the first time, if I press the back button and select the same video again, the layout is perfectly like I want it to be.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I have also noticed that this only happens if the previous activity (MainActivity) was in the same orientation than what the selected video is.

Comment: please check for onConfigurationChanged

Comment: @surya I just had a look into `onConfigurationChanged` and tested, but using it does not detect if the video was taking in portrait/landscape mode. Could you please post a answer explaining how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Is it a problem when you are loading a Landscape video in Portrait mode!!

Comment: onConfigurationChanged will get called if you are changing the Activity to Landsape and Portrait , you have to manual load the XML by your self android will not take care in the case of a Landscape video opened in portrait mode or Portrait video opened in Landscape mode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.

Instead of using `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the width and height, I first retrieve a `Bitmap` from the video file and then setting the orientation according to the width and hight of the `Bitmap`, as shown below:

```
private void rotateScreen() {
    try {
        //Create a new instance of MediaMetadataRetriever
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        //Declare the Bitmap
        Bitmap bmp;
        //Set the video Uri as data source for MediaMetadataRetriever
        retriever.setDataSource(this, mVideoUri);
        //Get one "frame"/bitmap - * NOTE - no time was set, so the first available frame will be used
        bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();

        //Get the bitmap width and height
        videoWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        videoHeight = bmp.getHeight();

        //If the width is bigger then the height then it means that the video was taken in landscape mode and we should set the orientation to landscape
        if (videoWidth > videoHeight) {
            //Set orientation to landscape
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        //If the width is smaller then the height then it means that the video was taken in portrait mode and we should set the orientation to portrait
        if (videoWidth < videoHeight) {
            //Set orientation to portrait
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        //error occurred
        Log.e("MediaMetadataRetriever", "- Failed to rotate the video");

    }
}
```